# Convert a system of second order ODEs into a system of first order ODEs?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

It is well-known that one can start with a second-order ODE and re-write it as a system of two first-order ODEs.

I have the below pair of coupled non-linear second-order ODEs for $x$ and $y$

$\gamma_1 \dot{x} - \gamma_2 ( \dot{x} - \dot{y} ) = (m_1 + m_2) d^2 \ddot{x} + I \ddot{x} + m_2 d^2 \ddot{y} + d(m_1 + m_2) g  x,$

$\gamma_2 (\dot{x}- \dot{y}) = m_2 d^2 \ddot{y} + I \ddot{y} + m_2 d^2 \ddot{x} + dm_2g y,  $

where $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, $m_1$, $m_2$, $g$, $d$ and $I$ are parameters of the system.

Is it possible to convert this into a system of four coupled non-linear first-order ODEs?

Comment: Sure, same method as with one, you replace $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ each with a new variable.

Comment: I wish to analyse the Jacobian of the system of first order ODEs which results, but if have $\dot{x} = u$ and $\dot{y} = v$, the  $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y} $ terms have coefficients in front of them?  I'm basically considering the stability of the above system.